# php curl : Rest API Post XML

Tags: php, xml, rest, curl, php-curl

I am trying to make a post request in php by building the xml with SimpleXML.

This is what the example XML I have to build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Orders>
 <Master>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <OrderCode>1001</OrderCode>
  <OrderYear>2016</OrderYear>
  <CustomerCode>0002</CustomerCode>
 </Master>
 <Detail>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <MasterID>1</MasterID>
  <ProductCode>246VIC53</ProductCode>
  <RequestedQuantity>2</RequestedQuantity>
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <MasterID>1</MasterID>
  <ProductCode>042COL75</ProductCode>
  <RequestedQuantity>1</RequestedQuantity>
 </Detail>
</Orders>
```

And this is how I am building it in php:

```
$ordersXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<orders></orders>");

$master = $ordersXML->addChild('Master');
$master->addChild('ID', '1');
$master->addChild('OrderCode', $order_id);
$master->addChild('CustomerCode', '0002');
$i=0;
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
    
    $detail = $ordersXML->addChild('Detail');
    $detail->addChild('ID', $i);
    $i += 1;
    $detail->addChild('MasterID', '1');
    $detail->addChild('ProductCode', get_post_meta($item->get_product_id(), '_sku', true));
    $detail->addChild('RequestedQuantity', $item->get_quantity());

}
```

And I am sending the post request via curl and by using ->asXML() in order to convert the actual XML to string like this:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);

//Set the Content-Type to text/xml.
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));

//Set CURLOPT_POST to true to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Attach the XML string to the body of our request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ordersXML->asXML());

//Tell cURL that we want the response to be returned as
//a string instead of being dumped to the output.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Execute the POST request and send our XML.
$result = curl_exec($curl);

//Do some basic error checking.
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

//Close the cURL handle.
curl_close($curl);
```

I am trying to print the result but its empty... I get no errors in debug. What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `case` important for your api? The expected XML has `Orders` but you add `orders` as main element.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thx for the remark, I changed it but with no luck...